# Update temporary table columns with two SELECTS instead of four

Tags: mysql

I want to update my min_odo and min_odo_pagal_virtual by one select. Is it possible in MySQL 5.1.41?

```
(min_odo, min_odo_pagal_virtual) = (SELECT min_odo, min_odo_pagal_virtual
        FROM km_statistika
        WHERE km_statistika.masinos_id = km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo.masinos_id AND min_odo != '0' AND km_statistika.data BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' AND '$iki_data_paieskai' ORDER BY km_statistika.data ASC LIMIT 1)
```

**Full code:**

```
UPDATE km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo SET min_odo = 
        (SELECT min_odo
        FROM km_statistika
        WHERE km_statistika.masinos_id = km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo.masinos_id AND min_odo != '0' AND km_statistika.data BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' AND '$iki_data_paieskai' ORDER BY km_statistika.data ASC LIMIT 1)
        , min_odo_pagal_virtual = 
        (SELECT min_odo_pagal_virtual
        FROM km_statistika
        WHERE km_statistika.masinos_id = km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo.masinos_id AND min_odo != '0' AND km_statistika.data BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' AND '$iki_data_paieskai' ORDER BY km_statistika.data ASC LIMIT 1)
        , max_odo = 
        (SELECT max_odo
        FROM km_statistika
        WHERE km_statistika.masinos_id = km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo.masinos_id AND max_odo != '0' AND km_statistika.data BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' AND '$iki_data_paieskai' ORDER BY km_statistika.data DESC LIMIT 1)
        , max_odo_pagal_virtual = 
        (SELECT max_odo_pagal_virtual
        FROM km_statistika
        WHERE km_statistika.masinos_id = km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo.masinos_id AND min_odo != '0' AND km_statistika.data BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' AND '$iki_data_paieskai' ORDER BY km_statistika.data DESC LIMIT 1);
```

**This is how I create my tmp table:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo` (masinos_id INT(11), min_odo INT(11), min_odo_pagal_virtual INT(11), max_odo INT(11), max_odo_pagal_virtual INT(11)) SELECT masinos_id, '' AS min_odo, '' AS min_odo_pagal_virtual, '' AS max_odo, '' AS max_odo_pagal_virtual FROM km_statistika WHERE data BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' AND '$iki_data_paieskai' GROUP BY masinos_id;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to you code  seems you need  the update for each  masinos_id with the related value for temp_table 
if this is true the you could an UPDATED   with JOIN

```
  UPDATE km_statistika_tmp_for_min_max_odo  km1
  INNER JOIN (
        select masinos_id, min_date, min_odo, max_odo, min_odo_pagal_virtual, max_odo_pagal_virtual
        from km_statistika  k 
        INNER JOIN  (
          SELECT masinos_id, min( data) min_data 
            FROM km_statistika  
            WHERE  min_odo != '0' 
            AND km_statistika.data 
            BETWEEN '$nuo_data_paieskai' 
            AND '$iki_data_paieskai' 
            GROUP BY masinos_id
        ) t on t.masinos_id = k.masinos_id 
            AND t.min_data = k.data
      )  km2 ON km1.masinos_id  = km2.masinos_id


  SET km1.min_odo = km2.min_odo,
      km1.max_odo = km2.max_odo,
      km1.min_odo_pagal_virtual = km2.min_odo_pagal_virtual,
      km1.max_odo_pagal_virtual = km2.max_odo_pagal_virtual,
```

anyway you should avoid  the use of php var in sql you are at risk for sql ijection  ..  be sure for proper sanitizing the var content of you should use prepared  statement and binding param